# how to disabled ng-repeat with button using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have list of stores which is shown based services with one accept button once user clicked that apply button i need to disabled that button, for listing i have used ng-repeat.how can i disable clicked apply button.how can i write apply function for disabled particular clicked service.once i applied it should be always disabled.

```js
.controller('CouponsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$ionicPopup',
    function($scope, $http, $window, $location, $ionicPopup) {
     
                $http.get('***').success(function(data,response) {

                    $scope.services = data;
                  
                });

        $scope.apply = function(_id) {
                   console.log(_id);
              
            }
   }
])
```

```html
<div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="service in services |  filter:query ">
  
 
<i style="margin-left:40px;color:white;font-size:14px:"> {{service.Store_Name}} </i>
  <i style="margin-left:40px;color:white;font-size:14px:"> {{service.Store_Address}} </i>
 <button ng-click="apply(service._id)" >apply</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set service as `clicked`:

   <button ng-click="apply(service._id); service.clicked = true;">apply</button>
2. Add ng-disabled to your button:

   <button ng-click="apply(service._id); service.clicked = true;" ng-disabled="service.clicked">apply</button>

PS
You should better pass entire service to `apply` not just ID, and set "clicked" property there.

**Update:**
See working plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/9ESdpjuHqHZYprNbbZ8F?p=preview

Comment: i have done something but if user clicked every button disabled

Comment: please can you explain me clearly i am new to this technology

Comment: In my example you set only particular service as clicked, so if user clicks button corresponding to that service - only that service should be disabled.

Comment: i have posted when i click apply button i am getting that particular id.here i need to disable particular id apply button.becoze its already applied

Comment: please share that one

Comment: Sorry, seems like I've forgotten to click save )) Here is the link
http://plnkr.co/edit/9ESdpjuHqHZYprNbbZ8F?p=preview

Comment: You should save service as clicked on the server (with another $http POST request), so if your page gets refreshed and your services are loaded again - the service will still be marked as clicked.